# how to filter in sequelize order.getProducts(req.params.productId)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to send get request to card like get card/:productId. is it possible to insert parameter for order instance ??

```
   const products = await order.getProducts(req.params.productId);
```

I just got all products in response

when I do

```
const products = await order.getProduct(req.params.productId);
```

I get

"order.getProduct is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do. Insertion can't be done during get operation on database.

Comment: is there any idea?

Comment: this is not the answer but is a comment.